# How can I reference a "@typeparam TModel" field in the Blazor (sub)-component?

Tags: c#, blazor, client-side, webassembly

VS-2019 Core 5 Blazor client-side component defines a @typeparam TModel to work with the

```
private List<TModel> _allModelRecs { get; set; }
```

as follows in code that follows.  Take note of (a) "ddlOtherModel_Value" and (b) the "UID_MODEL" field of the TModel class ...

```
// Select first 'Record'.
IDictionary<int, string> _ModelFiltersList = (Dictionary<int, string>)_ModelFiltersList.OrderBy(r => r.Value);
TModel _OtherModel = _allModelRecs.Where(r => r.**UID_MODEL** == _ModelFiltersList.First().Key);
int ddlOtherModel_Value = _OtherModel.**UID_MODEL**;
```

Since this component can and must work with different "TModel(s)" (Customer, Vehicle, Department...etc) I need to set the "ddlOtherModel_Value" to be the "key"-value of the TModel's instance/record.  The key-field name is different for each of the TModel(s) :  UID_CUSTOMER, UID_VEHICLE, UID_DEPARTMENT...etc.

In the code snippet above "UID_MODEL" is shown for this question -- it is NOT the actual key-field-name.

**Here is the question...**
How do I code for these variations in the actual TModel's key-name in place for "UID_MODEL"?

Your comments or questions or answers are welcome.  Thx  John

Comment: `@typeparam TItem @attribute [CascadingTypeParameter(nameof(TItem))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should not. UID should be defined on the abstract TModel.

If for some reason that is out of your hands then you will need to implement some extension to get the id. For example you could implement a wrapper class or a set of static extension methods. Another option is to use reflection to get the field starting with "UID" but this can be slow.

Comment: Thank you, @Frank...  I shall have another property in each model named "UID_KEY" that can be referenced from the abstract TModel.  Easy fix for me.  If I need other specific fields that need exposure to the TModel, I can easily add them to the actual model-class.ds.  Thanks

Comment: @JohnD I think, given what you've said and asked, that it will be useful for you to think about the Object Oriented paradigm in non-technical contexts. A ' pet animal' may have a name, but the sub-type of 'pet animal'  may be 'cat', 'dog', etc. It is not useful or realistic to introduce the type 'dog name' as something distinct from 'cat name', which is effectively what you have done. In real life there may a 'dog name catalogue' in use that is distinct from a 'cat name catalogue' but they would both be *instances* of a name catalogue *type* while 'name' remains name regardless of type context

Comment: @JohnD Are your model types not subtypes of TModel?

Comment: Thx Frank.  TModel is a Blazor @typeparam with the name "TModel" defined in the (sub)-component that is "used and displayed" by the PAGE-component.  The parent-page passes the model (Customer, Vehicle, Department etc.) as a parameter "TModel=Customer".  The sub-component has variables such as "List<TModel> _OtherModelData {get/set};".  Blazor allows that I can sort/filter/First() this list and it works that way in the code. BUT, it appears I cannot get the "...Where( r => r.UID_KEY == /somevalue/)" to work.  Also, I tried adding "UID_KEY" as a {get} returning UID_CUSTOMER; see next comment.

Comment: Further based on your second post, , perhaps I need to make a new base class (like Animal/MyTModel) with dogs and cats and fish like Customer, Vehicle and Department.   Comments?  Thx. John

Comment: @JohnD Well, unless there's something different about the Blazor conceptual model I can't see at the moment (I don't have a Blazor project open right now) the only two approaches I can think of are a) Declare a common type against which you can do common operations , so all your Customer, Vehicle, Department etc would offer common functionality, or b) Make your subcomponent accept Actions depending on the model type ... or something like that. Frankly I'd probably go the route of making an ISortable or ISearchable interface declaration that represents the UI functionality you want ....

Comment: Though come to think of it, you might want to look into ViewModels and declare a common viewmodel, which would not only offer the functionality you want, but maintain the view state (which is selected, which way the sorting is going, what filtering is applied) .... and then you could have some mapping code that takes your DTO (data model class) and stuff it into a common viewmodel class, which would be a list of sub-viewmodels, where each sub-viewmodel has it's own ID declaration. You could then leave the model classes as they are and implement a viewmodel factory that switches on the model

Comment: But for now probably the easiest for you is just make an abstract Model class  , or declare a common ISomethingIWantToDo interface and have all the models implement that

Comment: Thank you, Frank.  I like the idea of I-interface but I need to research and think about this some more.  I really appreciate your comments and guidance.  StackOverflow is asking to continue with "chat".  I leave this for now.  Thanks...John

Comment: Best of luck, John.